# Get occupancy per every 15-minute slot

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a room where we can only have XX number of people inside due to current limitations. They come at different times and stay for a different length of time.

I'm trying to get a sum of people currently inside for each 15-min period for a specific date. The server is MySQL 8.0.21 deployed on AWS RDS.

#### MySQL 8.0 Table: Booking

| ID | Name | PartySize | Date | BookedFrom | BookedTo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 2 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-01 08:30:00 | 2021-01-01 10:00:00 |
| 2 | Mary | 4 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-01 09:00:00 | 2021-01-01 11:00:00 |
| 3 | Nick | 3 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-01 10:30:00 | 2021-01-01 12:30:00 |

I also have a "helper table" with a time slot for each 24 hour 15-min slot

#### MySQL Table: Timeslot

| ID | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 00:15:00 |
| 3 | 00:30:00 |
| 35 | 08:30:00 |
| 37 | 09:00:00 |
| 38 | 09:15:00 |

For example, when I run this query below, I will get the correct count (6 people) for 09:30. What is the most efficient way to get this result for each 15-min slot? Please note that while the `BookedTo` (datetime field) value may be past midnight, I will always be only making date specific queries.

```
SELECT 
    t.id, b.date, t.time, SUM(b.partysize) AS total
FROM
    booking b,
    timeslot t
WHERE
    b.date = '2021-01-01' 
        AND t.time = '09:15:00'
        AND b.bookedfrom <= '2021-01-01 09:15:00'
        AND b.bookedto >= '2021-01-01 09:15:00'
```

Looking for this output for all times (including zeros)

| Slot_ID | Date | Time | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 33 | 2021-01-01 | 08:00:00 | 0 |
| 34 | 2021-01-01 | 08:15:00 | 0 |
| 35 | 2021-01-01 | 08:30:00 | 2 |
| 36 | 2021-01-01 | 08:30:00 | 2 |
| 37 | 2021-01-01 | 09:00:00 | 6 |
| 38 | 2021-01-01 | 09:15:00 | 6 |

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: @jarlh I'm using MySQL server

Comment: You have to use `LEFT JOIN` to get zero sums.

Comment: Why do you need to divide by 900 in your grouping? The timeslot table is already on 15-minute boundaries.

Comment: @Barmar I was trying different options

Comment: Do you want the results for a specific date?

Comment: @forpas YES! The query is for a specific date between 8-5pm

Comment: Also is the date part of BookedFrom and BookedTo always the same, or the booking may extend to the next date?

Comment: @forpas the actual date field does exist in the table (as date field) and I have edited the question to correctly show it. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @forpas Great question - yes the BookedTo field may extend to the next day. Mostly because the BookedFrom and BookedTo are saved as UTC - but I can figure that part (I hope)

Comment: Why does your sql say "blockedfrom" and your table say "bookedfrom"

Comment: What version of mysql

Comment: @CaiusJard Sorry about the typo, I have corrected the field names. It is MySQL 8.0.21

Comment: What is the purpose of the column Date in the table Booking? Is it always the date part of  BookFrom? If it is then it is redundant.

Comment: @forpas you are correct and it is somewaht redundant. It was the original design with only the reservation date (as date field) and reservation time (as time field) as two separate fields. The BookedFrom and BookedTo were added much later as `datetime` fields in order to get this occupancy count.

Comment: You said in the comments that *BookedTo field may extend to the next day*, so I'm curious how the answer that you accepted and the answer that you awarded the bounty to (not the same answer...) handle this issue.

Comment: @forpas First of all, thank you again for taking the time to answer the question. At the end, while I really wanted to use your code, I was unable to use it as the performance was just too slow. Your code took about 5 seconds to execute, while the other took about 0.08 seconds. Therefore, I had to find a workaround for my use. Again, your time and your help is much appreciated, and thanks to your different approach, I was able to learn something new. BTW, I decided to award the bounty to the new guy, just because we need more people answering questions, and this may give some encouragement.

Comment: What I still don't understand is how do you compare the time efficiency between my code and the others, since they don't produce the same result. I asked specific questions in the comments and wrote the code according to your answers. The other answers do not meet the requirement, as you explained it. So, how do they solve your problem since they do not take into account that *BookedTo field may extend to the next day*?

Comment: @forpas As I mentioned before, at the end, I had to find a workaround, and decided to only show results for the same date. Basically, while your code provided the desired results, it could not be used as a solution, just because the query was too slow, and therefore, unusable for my specific application. I have not doubt that you could have provided the same solution as the other answers. Your reputation score, along with your answer, clearly demonstrated your superior skills, and I'm grateful having you as a part of this great community. I hope you don't mind the new guy getting the bounty.

Comment: *decided to only show results for the same date* which is not what you asked for. What is the point of the clarifications that you made in the comments after I asked them? I don't mind any guy getting the bounty, if their solution meets the requirement of the question, but it does not. And I do mind when I post an answer that does meet the requirement and is compared to answers that do not do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  t.id as slot_id,
  coalesce(b.date, '2021-01-01') as date,
  t.time,
  coalesce(sum(b.partysize),0) as total
FROM
  timeslot t
  LEFT JOIN booking b
  ON t.time >= TIME(b.bookedfrom) AND t.time < TIME(b.bookedto) AND b.date = '2021-01-01'
WHERE
  t.time BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '17:00:00'
GROUP BY
  t.id,
  b.date,
  t.time
```

Now, you have some confusing other requirements, but basically this works because multiple rows of timeslot will match to a single row of booking because of the time range expressed.

The confusing requirements are, you say it's only for 8-5pm, but "bookings might extend to the next day".. does it mean that a booking will start at 4pm and finish at 9am the next day? in which case you might need to adjust the `AND b.date = '2021-01-01'` to be more like `AND (DATE(b.bookedfrom) = '2021-01-01' OR DATE(b.bookedto) = '2021-01-01')` ...

Comment: You can use [fiddle](https://sqlifiddle.com) to test queries on various RDBMSs

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I prefer db<>fiddle myself; more dbs, but none of them work well with a cellphone

Comment: @CaiusJard Unfortunately, it is not returning any values. Also, each booking has a different party size, and I'm counting the total number of people inside, not a number of bookings.

Comment: Changed it to use sum(partysize).. but it returns data when I run it...

Comment: @CaiusJard - Thank you! It is working for me now too. Thank you for the detailed answer and also for including the count for parties. It might be handy as well. You got my up-vote and I will have to wait 24 hours before the bounty is awarded. Your time and help is appreciated!

Comment: @CaiusJard your solution is not ok .. the coalesce for DATE will give invalid data for null values ...

Comment: @Mr.P can you explain more what you mean?

Comment: @WayBehind note that I used < for the end of the time range because in my mind a party that is booked in from 1pm til 2pm shouldn't be counted as being in the room in the 2pm til 2:15 slot (they should have left by 2pm).. If you do consider that they are present in the 2 til 215 slot, you can use <=

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks for pointing that out! You are correct. That is very important, and I will definitely take that in consideration. Thanks again for your efforts! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CTE` that returns the specific date for which you want the results, which may not be the same as the column `Date` in `Booking` and `CROSS` join it to `Timeslot`.
The result should be `LEFT` joined to `Booking` and then aggregate:

```
WITH cte(Date) AS (SELECT '2021-01-01')
SELECT t.ID, t.time, c.Date, 
       COALESCE(SUM(b.PartySize), 0) Total
FROM cte c CROSS JOIN Timeslot t 
LEFT JOIN Booking b
ON b.BookedFrom <= CONCAT(c.Date, ' ', t.time)
AND b.BookedTo >= CONCAT(c.Date, ' ', ADDTIME(t.time, '00:15:00'))
WHERE t.time BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '17:00:00'
GROUP BY t.ID, c.Date, t.time
```

Since `BookedFrom` and `BookedTo` may not contain the same date, it is not safe to compare only the time parts of the 2 columns to the column `time` of `Timeslot`.
This is why all these conditions in the `ON` clause are needed.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=903aeb2e2205fb1de25f49cca8d1563a).

Comment: It's probably a bug to make the end inclusive

Comment: @CaiusJard no it is not a bug, because I add 15 mins to `time`. If I added `00:14:59` then I would change `>=` to `>`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and the sample of the code! Everything seems to be working correctly. I will have to run some test to see if any of these versions is faster and also if I can translate this to Django ORM. The only reason I want to do that instead of using a raw SQL is because the app is timezone aware and the bookedrom and bookedto are stored in UTC. Again, your help and your time is much appreciated! You got my upvote and the bounty will be awarded tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

this query works great ... if you wanna have all dates for all slots .. you will have to have a date table too (ideally within timeslot -> cross join dates and timeslots) ...

use inner join if you wanna get only matching dates and timeslots ..

```
SELECT t.id as slot_id
, b.date 
, t.time as slot 
, sum(ifnull(party_size,0)) as total
FROM test.timeslot t
LEFT JOIN test.booking b 
ON t.time BETWEEN time(b.booked_from) AND time(b.booked_to)
GROUP BY t.id 
, b.date 
, t.time;
```

for all timeslots and selected dates:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gLt2Fs8HTDUakMahZHxcTi/0

for matching timeslots and dates:

```
SELECT t.id as slot_id
, b.date 
, t.time as slot 
, sum(ifnull(party_size,0)) as total
FROM test.timeslot t
JOIN test.booking b 
ON t.time BETWEEN time(b.booked_from) AND time(b.booked_to)
GROUP BY t.id 
, b.date 
, t.time;
```

Comment: WOW, this is great and seems to be doing what I need! Let me run some tests and see if I can implement that to my app. BTW what exactly is the `1=1`?

Comment: that's just my 'hack' .. makes debugging easier :) feel free to remove it

Comment: You got me confused for a sec. LOL. Thank you! Thank you for the detailed answer and also for including the db-fiddle. You got my up-vote. Because of the rules, I will have to wait 24 hours before the bounty can be awarded. Your time and help is appreciated!

Comment: no worries :) happy to help ... lemme know if there is anything else you need help with ...